# TWS job is getting abended

Tags: tivoli-work-scheduler

While executing the job, I am getting below error
Job.sh is the script - while executing it in tws I am getting below error

path of the script - job.sh: sqlplus: not found

Can any please help on this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Tivoli works, but you are writing to run a "job.sh" script, so I assume it is a shell script.
Normally when working with oracle it is a good idea to enter absolute paths, so your script could be

```
   #!/bin/sh
   $ORACLE_HOME=<your path of oracle installation>
   $ORACLE_SID=<your instance name>
   $PWD=<Position of your sql script>
    ..........
   $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus login/password @$PWD/script.sql
```

I hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi splease, thanks for the info, yes this work for me

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Unix variable @$PWD in the PATH for  the sdript.sql.  TWS doesn't use any variable in the .profile file by default.  You can do two things to correct this:

1. Added the TWS command as ". /home/.profile;@$PWD/script.sql"
2. Update /home/.jobmanrc with all variable from the .profile.

The .jobmanrc is the TWS job run-control file.